# Correctly Sort Numbered Unordered List Items

Tags: javascript, html, list, numerical

I'm having an issue trying to sort the list-items within an unordered-list when the values within the list-items are numbers. Sorting alphanumerically does not seem to be the answer and I am unsure of what to change in order to ensure the list is displayed in the correct order.

The problem occurs when the outcome like the following, obviously 10 does not come before 2:

- 1 Meter
- 10 Meter
- 2 Meter

Below is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(".filtersDropDown").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).children('li').sort(function(a, b){
        return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="specificationFiltersDropDown1047" class="filtersDropDown">
      <ul>
         <li class="selected">
            <a class="allFilterDropDownOptions">All</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a class="filterItemUnselected" data-option-id="1209">1 Meter (3ft)</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a class="filterItemUnselected" data-option-id="1288">10 Meter (33ft)</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a class="filterItemUnselected" data-option-id="1291">2 Meter (7ft)</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: What is data('position') value?

Comment: You're dealing with the good-old "string vs number" sort problem.  "10" *does* come before "2".  You'll need to convert the first "word" to a number.  Or add something in your data to allow sorting by a number instead of a string.

Comment: will a number always come before a string in your list?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, please keep in mind I'm an absolute moron when it comes to coding so I unfortunately need things to be explained as if they where for a child. That being said, any suggestion on what or how to add 'something' to my data?

Comment: In this list, yes a number will always come before the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by using the `parseInt()` function. This will turn character numbers into numbers.

Also, there were few errors on your code ass i couldnt find the data position and no `.find('ul')` for your sort.

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

```js
$(".filtersDropDown").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).find('ul').children('li').sort(function(a, b){
    var a = parseInt($(a).find('a').text().split(" ")[0]);
    var b = parseInt($(b).find('a').text().split(" ")[0]);
        return b < a ? 1 : -1;
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="specificationFiltersDropDown1047" class="filtersDropDown">
      <ul>
         <li class="selected">
            <a class="allFilterDropDownOptions">All</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a class="filterItemUnselected" data-option-id="1209">1 Meter (3ft)</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a class="filterItemUnselected" data-option-id="1288">10 Meter (33ft)</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a class="filterItemUnselected" data-option-id="1291">2 Meter (7ft)</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Geraldo, I have no doubt my code had errors in it... I'm really useless at this (Designer not coder). Let me give yours a shot and I'll let you know how it pans out!

Comment: Jajaja it happens, hope it works. If it does pliss dont forget to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".filtersDropDown ul").each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).find('li').sort(function(a, b){
  var a = parseInt($(a).find('a').text().match(/\d+/),10);
  var b = parseInt($(b).find('a').text().match(/\d+/),10);
  if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)){
    return 1;
  }
  return b < a ? 1 : -1;

  }));
});
```

I have used parseInt with regex and put a if condition to put All on top. Hopefully you are looking for this. :-)

```
  <div id="specificationFiltersDropDown1047" class="filtersDropDown">
  <ul>
     <li class="selected">
        <a class="allFilterDropDownOptions">All</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a class="filterItemUnselected" data-option-id="1209">1 Meter (3ft)</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a class="filterItemUnselected" data-option-id="1288">10 Meter (33ft)</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a class="filterItemUnselected" data-option-id="1291">2 Meter (7ft)</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
```